# Unpermitted parameter: :user_id even if it's already permitted

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6.1

I'm working in a Rails app, where Photo and User are the main models. They are associated, Photo belongs to Users, and User has many Photos.

Via API (Postman), I'm able to create new records for Photos correctly with a user_id. However I'm not able to do the same via the interface, as I'm hitting this error

> Unpermitted parameter: :user_id

**photos_controller.rb**

```
class Api::PhotosController < ApplicationController

    skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token

    respond_to :json
    
    # before_action :set_photo
   
    def index
        photos = Photo.all
        render json: photos, status: 200
    end

    def show
    end

    def create
        photo = Photo.new(
            title: photo_params[:title],
            image: photo_params[:image],
            user_id: photo_params[:user_id]
        )
        if photo.save
            render json: photo, status: 200
        else
            render json: {error: "there was an error"}
        end
    end

    private
        def photo_params
            params.permit([
                :title,
                :image,
                :user_id
            ])
        end        
        def set_photo
            @photo = Photo.find(params[:id])
        end

end
```

**form for Photo**

```
<%= form_with(model: photo, local: true) do |form| %>
<% if photo.errors.any? %>
<div id="error_explanation">
    <h2><%= pluralize(photo.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this photo from being saved:</h2>

    <ul>
        <% photo.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
        <% end %>
    </ul>
</div>
<% end %>

<div class="form-group">
    <%= form.label :image %>
    <%= form.text_field :image, class: 'form-control' %>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <%= form.label :title %>
    <%= form.text_field :title, class: 'form-control' %>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <%= form.label :user_id %>
    <%= form.number_field :user_id, class: 'form-control' %>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <% if photo.persisted? %>
    <div class="float-right">
        <%= link_to 'Destroy', photo, method: :delete, class: "text-danger", data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
    </div>
    <% end %>

    <%= form.submit class: 'btn btn-primary' %>

    <% if photo.persisted? %>
    <%= link_to "Cancel", photo, class: "btn btn-link" %>
    <% else %>
    <%= link_to "Cancel", photos_path, class: "btn btn-link" %>
    <% end %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

sample call via Postman

[image]

and output via rails console for that last record

```
3.0.0 :002 > Photo.last
  Photo Load (16.6ms)  SELECT "photos".* FROM "photos" ORDER BY "photos"."id" DESC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
 => #<Photo id: 31, image: "sampleforSO", title: "sampleforSO", created_at: "2021-02-06 15:02:05.153170000 +0000", updated_at: "2021-02-06 15:02:05.153170000 +0000", user_id: 1> 
3.0.0 :003 >
```

PS: Working with:

Rails version             6.1.1
Ruby version              ruby 3.0.0p0

Comment: Do you have a `PhotosController` outside the API scope?  That's probably what's being used when you're submitting the form.  That may not have the `user_id` white-listed.

Comment: @SteveTurczyn right on! I didn't think in that controller, just permitted user_id there and it works.

Comment: That's great, glad to help!